# What does auto and content value of flex-basis do

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to dive deep into flexbox and was studying the `flex-basis`. Till now i understood that it is used to specify width or height of a flex item, depending on flex-direction is row or column. But I am not a able to get what do `auto` (it is the default value) value of `flex-basis` do?

And `flex-basis` also has one other value `content`. About this value, what [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis#values) is confusing me a lot.

Can i get clear explanation on what these two values (`auto` and `content`) exactly do?

Comment: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-flex-basis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference in the behavior of those two values is what they do when the `width` property is defined for the element.

### `flex-basis: content`

The "content" value will just set the width according to the element's content. It doesn't matter if you've defined a width for the element through the `width` property, it would be ignored.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul li {
  background-color: green;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  flex-basis: content;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>Element</li>
      <li>Element</li>
      <li>Element</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

### `flex-basis: auto`

The "auto" value verifies if the `width` property was defined. If so, that will be the element's width. If no, it will fall back to `flex-basis: content`.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul li {
  background-color: green;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  flex-basis: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>Element</li>
      <li>Element</li>
      <li>Element</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```